# Issue with Setting value to dynamic HTML DropDownListFor MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My view is collection of question that is rendered as textbox, dropdown and checkboxes. These question are stored in database.

For my view I have created a viewmodel

```
public class SpecialProgram
{
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswerList { get; set; }

    // other prop
}  

public class QuestionAnswer
{
    // other prop

    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string ControlType { get; set; }

    public int QuestionSortOrder { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

now here is my view

```
@model MyApplication.SpecialProgram

@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePage", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "formData" }))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuestionAnswerList.Count(); i++)
    {
        // other stuff......

        else if (@Model.QuestionAnswerList[i].ControlType == "DropDown")
        {
           <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="input-group" style="padding: .15em .15em .15em .15em">
                 <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:350px; text-align: left;">@Model.QuestionAnswerList[i].Question</span>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(mod => mod.QuestionAnswerList[i].Answer, Model.QuestionAnswerList[i].DataList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control placeholder-color answers", style = "width: 150px;" })
             </div>
         </div>
      }
   }
}
```

Now lets say My data List is a Yes&No List. here is how i am getting my values from database and passing my values to View

```
public List<QuestionAnswer> MYMethod()
{
     List<QuestionAnswer> qadata = new List<QuestionAnswer>();

     List<SelectListItem> YesNoList = new List<SelectListItem>();
     YesNoList.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1" });
     YesNoList.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0" });         

     qa.DataList = YesNoList;

     // the qa.Answer here is 1. which is the selected dropdown value saved in db. I want yes to be pre-selected on page load. But for some reason On page load I get default value "--Select--"


}
```

For testing purposes only I tried setting value to dropdown. this works

```
var data = '@Model.QuestionAnswerList[2].Answer';
$('#ddlMYddl').val(data)
```

But using jquery does not really solve my problem. i want @Html.DropDownListFor to work

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(mod => mod.QuestionAnswerList[i].Answer, Model.QuestionAnswerList[i].DataList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control placeholder-color answers", style = "width: 150px;" })
```

to summarize. The dropdown rendered with above code has 3 select options(yes, no , --select--). Based on Answer from DB on page load ddlMYddl should have "Yes" selected but i get --Select--

Where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in `MYMethod`, do you know which is selected when creating the list? If so you can use the `selected` property of the `SelectedListItem` and set it to true.

```
List<SelectListItem> YesNoList = new List<SelectListItem>();
YesNoList.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1", Selected = true });
YesNoList.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0" });
```

Comment: Yes i noticed that works. My question was why this @Html.DropDownListFor(mod => mod.QuestionAnswerList[i].Answer, Model.QuestionAnswerList[i].DataList,..... does not work